# Magic mouse 2 is not recognized

Tags: bluetooth, mojave, mouse

On my MacBookPro 2017 I was using a wireless keyboard and a magic mouse 2. I didn't used the wireless devices for a week, and now apple's wireless keyboard works well, but the magic mouse is not being discovered by the mac.
BT works as the keyboard works, I charged the mouse many times, but as the Apple removed led indicators it is hard to say if it was chargin or it is on.
I removed the device from the BT list to discover it again, but that didn't help.
I use Mojave 10.14.2

Comment: When you removed the mouse to discover it again, does it show up as “discoverable?”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that magic mouse 2 can be forced to connect to mac via connecting it to it via a lightning cable (mac shows a notification that mouse is now connected, then you can disconnect, mouse reboots and is usable after a couple of seconds)

Answer (score 2):

There could be several issues:

- **Make sure your device is turned on**

> The Magic Mouse and Magic Mouse 2 have a slide switch on the bottom of the device. Slide the switch to turn on the device. On the Magic Mouse, the green LED briefly lights up. On the Magic Mouse 2, green coloring is visible beneath the switch.

- **Make sure your  devices are setup with your Mac**

See [here how to set it up.](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201178)

If you charge your mouse wiring a lightning cable then you can go to Bluetooth preferences to see the charge level.

- **Turn Bluetooth on**

Go to the Apple menu -> System preferences and then Bluetooth on.

([Source](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204621#connectissue))

Comment: the device is turned on, the device is not visable anyhow, so I can't check the charge level. BT is on as the wireless keyboard works.

Answer (score 1):

**This worked for me:**

Press <kbd>option ⌥</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd>  and click on bluetooth menu bar icon. You'll see an option to "Reset the bluetooth module". Click this and your mouse will connect automatically after reset :D

Found this solution on Lifewire website.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, MacBook was unable to pair with Magic Mouse. Even after removing the mouse from the Bluetooth device list, it did not appear again in the list of nearby Bluetooth devices to re-pair.

Turns out my Wi-Fi was somehow the issue. After switching Wi-Fi off, I was able to connect the Magic Mouse as normal. The mouse kept working fine after bringing Wi-Fi back online.